# Question on square roots of complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

LeI have a function $f(x)$ where $x\in R$ and $|x|<1$. Now, I can write $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}g(x)$ for some non-divergent $g(x)$ in the domain of definition of $x$.
Can I write the following:
$$\sqrt{f(x)}=\sqrt{\sqrt{1-x^2}g(x)}=\sqrt{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\sqrt{g(x)}=(1-x^2)^{1/4}\sqrt{g(x)}$$
? If not, why?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the square root of a complex map is ambiguous. For example you can’t get a continuous square root map on $\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}$.

The square root of $e^{i\pi}$ can be $e^{i\dfrac{\pi}{2}}$ or $e^{-i\dfrac{\pi}{2}}$

Comment: Yes, but here's is what I don't quite get: in the above example, $\sqrt{1-x^2}$  is always positive (and non-zero). So, why can't I just do what I write in the question?

Comment: The issue is not with $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ but with $\sqrt{g(x)}$ if $g$ is supposed to be a complex map.

Comment: So, what are the restrictions that we must impose on $g(x)$ in order to be able to write $\sqrt{\sqrt{1-x^2}g(x)}=\sqrt{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\sqrt{g(x)}$?

Comment: If you restrict the image of $g$ to a simply connected subset of $\mathbb C \setminus\{0\}$ the square root can be uniquely defined.

Comment: For every $x$ such that $|x|<1$, $h=\sqrt{1-x^2}$(for the particular $x$) and $g$ are real and complex numbers respectively. So, for a particular $x$ we write $h=|r|=r>0$ and $g=\alpha+i\beta$ for some $r,\alpha, \beta$. We can now write $g$ in polar (complex) coordinates as $g=|g|\ e^{i\phi}$. So, as I see it, the ambiguity comes only from the phase of $g$ and not from $h$. If this argument holds, then we can do what I am asking in the question. So, where does this argument go wrong?

Comment: The argument goes wrong if the phase of $g$ can vary of $2\pi$ or more.

Comment: What do you mean? Isn't every phase factor define modulo $2\pi$? Oh, maybe you mean that this is exactly the reason for which we have to define a domain in which the phase factor does not have this ambiguity and work in that domain consistently?